# how can i disable a body style for only one component

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend

I want to disable `overflow-y: hidden` style for only one component. This style is in my style.scss like so

```
body {
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

I tried this in my component but it did not work.

```
<div class="div1" style="overflow-y: visible !important;">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Can you try to put

```
.visibleClass{overflow-y: visible ;}
```

to style.css under body css attribute

in appcomponent.html add activate event to `router-outlet`

```
<router-outlet (activate)="showHideNav($event)"></router-outlet>
```

then in component.ts

```
 showHideNav(event){
    event instanceof YourComponent ? document.body.classList.add("visibleClass") :
                                     document.body.classList.remove("visibleClass")
  }
```

Comment: You should not be using the `!important` tag on your first line of CSS. It's unnessecary here .

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because this `div` is inside of an invisible `body` and there's no way to tell body to display it without being displayed itself.

In you case without changing the architecture it's impossible.

You need to do something like the code below.

```html
<body>
  <div class="new-body-root"> <!-- move all body styles here -->
    ... all the code
  </div>
  <div class="div1"> <!-- now it's always visible, hide it when you don't need it -->
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The body isn't invisble, it has an invisible overflow

Comment: did I write a different thing in the answer? He needs to change architecture that `overflow-y: hidden` and all other body logic would apply on `class="new-body-root"`.