# How to create two login pages in angular application

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have an angular 6 application in which users can watch TV channel videos based on his/her subscription.
It is designed to have login page and the url is  http://mytv/login. On successful login, it goes to player page where users can watch videos.
There are 3 components
App component
Login component
Player component
App component has header and footer, using router outlet login and player components are displayed.
Now,the customers want to watch videos from Amazon Fire TV so a new login page is designed but it should not have header and footer.
Say new login url - http://mytv/firetv_login.
On hitting this I create one local storage to indicate fire tv login.
As this component will be loaded after app component I am not able to hide header and footer using ngIf.
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You can use strategy in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62174020/how-can-i-disable-a-body-style-for-only-one-component/62174311#62174311

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, your `app-component` is probably your main component and possibly be something like this:

app-component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

and your route is possibly like this:

```
const routes = [
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'player', component: PlayerComponent},
    {path: 'firetv', component: FireTVComponent},
]
```

A very simple way is to use a toggle in your `app-component`, possibly hook up to *router events* and toggle the header & footer. It's certainly a simpler method without much changes.

---

There's a more structured way by leveraging route (involving more changes):

The changes would require you to wrap a layout component, you would need 2 layout component:

blank-layout.component.html (This is a root component for views with no header & footer)

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

layout.component.html (This is a root component for views with header & footer)

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

And your routes will be like the following

```
const routes = [
    {path: 'firetv_login', component: BlankLayoutComponent, children:[
        {path: '', component: FireTVLoginComponent}
    ]},
    {path: '', component: LayoutComponent, children:[
        {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
        {path: 'player', component: PlayerComponent}
    ]},
]
```

your `AppComponent` will simply be `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Advantages:

- You don't have to deal with toggling the layout, manage state if the header & footer is hidden and when to hide it. This way, you define a layout and the routes decides whether the header & footer should be visible.
- It a more structured way, and you can modify the routes to add more pages
- You can add more layout e.g., a page where you have header, but no footer.

Comment: I have tried the given structured way and it works great. Thank you!