# Change string value in function of the current displayed component

Tags: angular, binding

I have a navbar in my app component with a string within and I would like to change it's content when I'm navigating, for example :
Index: "Here, you can see a list",
Contact: "Here you can send a mail"

I don't know how to get the current active component from the app component in order to change its content and I would like to know if I have to use `*ngIf` to display the string in function of the component.

AppComponent HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <aclass="nav-link item-navbar" routerLink="/home">
           Home
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link item-navbar" routerLink="/contact">
          Contact
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <span *ngIf="home">{{myString}}</span>
       <span *ngIf="contact">{{myString}}</span>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I only have this in the TS (this doesn't get the current component name)

```
     comp: any;
     myString: string;

  ngOnInit() {
   if(this.comp == 'home'){
     this.myString = 'home';
     }
   else{
     this.myString = "contact";
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62174020/how-can-i-disable-a-body-style-for-only-one-component/62174311#62174311

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: You're welcome hope it helps you :)